# Hyperledger Indy basic concepts

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-indy, decentralized-identity

I am reading the Indy walkthrough:

https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-sdk/blob/master/docs/getting-started/indy-walkthrough.md

and I am trying to figure out what is the Indy nodes pool?

And conceptually what is a pool?

And when we talk about Sovrin network which is the relationship between network, Sovrin pool, nodes, and ledger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [Indy node](https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-node) is application running on the machines participating in a Hyperledger Indy network.
- Indy nodes pool is just an interconnected network of Indy nodes. This commonly refers Hyperledger Indy network you can run in [docker](https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-sdk#how-to-start-local-nodes-pool-with-docker) for example. Network of Indy nodes is maintaining the state of ledger, verifying transactions.
- Sovrin network is particular instance of Hyperledger Indy network. You can browse transactions on Sovrin network [here](https://indyscan.io/). Note there's multiple Sovrin networks such as MainNet, TestNet, BuilderNet.